# Помогите решить задачу на python!

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, польская-запись

Боб любит формализм во всем, включая запись математических выражений, поэтому при их записи он ставит скобки так, чтобы каждая операция выделялась своей парой скобок. Например, выражение (a+b+c)∗d он запишет как (((a+b)+c)∗d) или как ((a+(b+c))∗d), а выражение a∗b+c∗d как ((a∗b)+(c∗d)). Таким образом, количество пар скобок в выражениях Боба всегда равно количеству операций, а для операции, которая выполняется последней, пара скобок всегда ограничивает все выражение.

Алиса считает такой перфекционизм избыточным и старается ставить скобки только там, где они нужны для правильных вычислений. Например, в выражении (a+b+c)∗d скобки убрать уже нельзя, поскольку выражение a+b+c∗d по математическим правилам задает другой порядок применения операций, и результаты вычисления этих двух выражений могут различаться. А вот в выражении
a+(b+c) скобки убрать уже можно, поскольку для сложения имеет место сочетательное свойство или, как говорят математики, аксиома ассоциативности. Также можно убрать скобки и в выражении (a∗b)+(c∗d), поскольку по договоренностям умножение выполняется раньше, чем сложение.

Напишите программу, которая перепишет выражение, записанное Бобом, в тот вид который нравится Алисе. Обратите внимание, что программа должна просто убрать все избыточные скобки. Другие преобразования делать нельзя. Полученное выражение должно иметь результат вычислений, совпадающий с результатом исходного выражения, при любых значениях параметров.

Формат входных данных: На вход в единственной строке поступает правильно записанное арифметическое выражение, состоящие из имен параметров, скобок и операций "+" и "*". Каждый параметр записывается в виде одной строчной буквы латиницы. Имена параметров не повторяются и встречаются в алфавитном порядке, таким образом, количество операций не превосходит 25. Выражение содержит как минимум одну операцию. Каждая операция в выражении выделяется своей парой скобок, как записано в условии задачи.

Формат выходных данных: Программа должна вывести исходное выражение без избыточных скобок. Порядок следования параметров в ответе должен совпадать с порядком в исходном выражении. В частности, это означает что для теста (a+b) ответ b+a будет считаться ошибочным.

Sample Input 1:

(a+b)

Sample Output 1:

a+b

Sample Input 2:

((a+(b+c))*d)

Sample Output 2:

(a+b+c)*d

Sample Input 3:

((ab)+(cd))

Sample Output 3:

ab+cd

**Попробовал решить через SymPy:**

```
import sympy
text = str(sympy.simplify(str(input())))
text_new = ""

for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i] == " ":
        text_new = text.replace(" ", "")

print(text_new)
```

Читал что можно через обратную польскую запись реализовать но не получилось

Comment: Начинай. Будет проблемы - поможем.

Comment: А что делает `text_new = text.replace(" ", "")`, если по условию пробелов нет?

Comment: Мне не совсем понятен третий пример, ведь в условии не сказано, что знак умножения может опускаться.

Comment: @rotabor там возвращается с пробелами строка

Comment: "состоящие из имен параметров, скобок и операций "+" и "*"" - откуда тут пробелы взялись? Значит, первая подзадача, которую нужно решить - это получить в программе строку именно в том виде, в котором она подаётся на вход.

Comment: @rotabor там после упрощения выражения возле "+" пробелы остаются

Comment: @rotabor а на выходе нужно получить строку полностью без пробелов

Comment: Этот пакет не подойдёт, так как он меняет порядок операндов. Нужно решить задачу без применения каких-то готовых решений. Это несложно.

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка № 1. Когда можно убрать скобки:

1. Если выражение в скобках является слагаемым в другом выражении.
2. Если выражение в скобках является произведением.
3. Если это последняя операция в выражении.

Подсказка № 2. Если допустимы выражения вида `ab`, но не `a(` или `)c`, то `ab` можно просто считать как один параметр, убрать с него скобки и в таком же виде передать на выход. Это значит, что при анализе выражения нужно допускать многобуквенные имена параметров.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку